# Why do I see sourceMappingURL appear after webpack and commit

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have made a small modification to an html. After webpack commit I see this in diff

```
sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJzb etc.
```

I don't remember to have ever seen this. What does it mean ?

Answer (score 1):

Webpack is generating a source map for that particular output file and is appending a reference to the source map's location in the `sourceMappingURL` field automatically as part of your Webpack build.

In this case, it looks like an inline sourcemap instead of an external file, so the map itself is constructed from the base64-encoded JSON data there.

In your webpack config, you should see an entry for `devtool`: that's the setting that turns on source map generation and allows you to choose a particular source map type or disable it altogether.